# Facebook Ad Image Upload size check validation

Tags: facebook

When creating an Ad and trying to Always get the error:

> Dimension requirement: 600 x 360 pixels

I use Fireworks to create the image, and have tried saving in both JPG and PNG format (with and without layers)... always get this error. The image is definitely 600x360.

Comment: I have the same problem using Chrome, probably a bug

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with Chrome. Works fine in Safari.